# Database connection for prepared statements

Tags: mysql, odbc, timeout, connection, prepared-statement

Using an ODBC connection to a mysql database, the connection times-out after a period of 8 hours (the default).

In order for my application to be resilient, it must recreate this connection to issue a prepared statement query.

**Is it possible to issue a new database connection for a prepared statement?**

Does it make sense to do so?

It appears like prepared statements are created on a connection basis.

The current solution is to :

1. Reconnect
2. Re-prepare the queries
3. Execute query

Answer (score 0):

No, prepared statements are tied to a connection, not the other way around. Your current way of handling a timed out connection is fine.

Comment: are you able to confirm this with some relevant documentation? i have tried to search but could not find anything useful. I would like to know more information about the relationship between a prepared statement and a database connection. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, having the connection opened to SQL database for 8 hours is a bad practise. Do you have some long-running operation, that requires so much time? Then consider having a stored procedure in your database, that should dump results into some temporary table, which you can check later.

But normally, the application should release the connection (and, ahh, all prepared statements with it) ASAP. To speedup the connection opening, you can use connection pooling (it should exist for ODBC as well). Connection pool will check that connection is "alive" before returning it to application, for example, see **validationQuery** parameter for [Java DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html).

Comment: yes this is a long running process. when data flow becomes very low, the mysql connection is seldom used. Connection pooling is a good idea, thanks for the link